# Best practices regarding types mapping

Tags: c#, architecture, extension-methods

I want to ask some questions about best practices regarding mapping types and using extension methods in C#. I know this topic has been discussed multiple times over past few years, but I've read a lot of posts and still have doubts.

The problem I encountered was extending class that I own with "convert" functionality. Let's say that I have class "Person" that represents an object which will be used by some logic. I also have a class "Customer" that represents a response from external API (actually there will be more than one API, so I need to map each API's response to common type: Person). I have access to both classes' source code and theoretically can implement my own methods there. I need to convert Customer to Person so I can save it to database. The project doesn't use any automatic mappers.

I have 4 possible solutions in mind:

1. .ToPerson() method in Consumer class. It's simple, but it seems like breaking the Single Responsibility pattern to me, especially that the Consumer class is mapped to other classes (some required by another external API) as well, so it would need to contain multiple mapping methods.
2. Mapping constructor in Person class taking Consumer as an argument. Also easy and also seems like breaking Single Responsibility pattern. I'd need to have multiple mapping constructors (since there will be class from another API, providing the same data as Consumer but in slightly different format)
3. Converters class with extension methods. This way I can write .ToPerson() method for Consumer class and when another API is introduced with it's own NewConsumer class, I can just write another extension method and keep it all in the same file. I've heard an opinion that extension methods are evil in general and should be used only if absolutely necessary so that's what is holding me back. Otherwise I like this solution
4. Converter/Mapper class. I create separate class that will handle conversions and implement methods that will take source class instance as an argument and return destination class instance.

To sum up, my problem can be reduced to number of questions (all in context to what I described above):

1. Is putting conversion method inside (POCO?) object (like .ToPerson() method in Consumer class) considered breaking single responsibility pattern?
2. Is using converting constructors in (DTO-like) class considered breaking single responsibility pattern? Especially if such class can be converted from multiple source types, so multiple converting constructors would be required?
3. Is using extension methods while having access to original class source code considered bad practice? Can such behavior be used as viable pattern for separating logic or is it an anti-pattern?

Comment: Your question is too broad and mainly opinion-based. Please provide minimal but complete, and verifiable example illustrating your problem... Please have a look on how to ask questions on SO here : http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Or move this question to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Stackexchange seems like a perfect place for this question. Thanks, topic can be closed now :)

Comment: if you did repost there it would be best if you delete it here (better than closing it)

Answer (score 2):

Since this is more of a subjective one, please do not mark as answer, everyone has their own ways, and no implementation is objectively the best or better then others.

1 and 2 introduces Coupling. I would not go for them.

For number 3, Extension methods themselves break many rules (at least they brake the rules in my self-book of programming). Many concerns there.

When you create an extension method on an instance like IsValidEMail() on type System.String, what happens is, a static method is created accepting the string instance as a parameter. You don't see this of course unless you decompile the output assembly.

```
public static IsValidEMail(string instance);
```

Then, the following code block works flawlessly instead of throwing null pointer exception:

```
string nullEMail = null;
bool isValidEMail = nullEMail.IsValidEMail();
```

Another thing which make me dislike the extension methods is Linq.

Linq consists heavily of extension methods. When developers (espacially juniors) see the Count() method on an IEnumerable instance, they may use it without caution. Would they know what this method does internally? No. They would just think that it is the equivalent of the Count property of concrete list or dictionary objects and will call it inside another loop, and you, as a senior programmer, will go fix the production performance issue by analyzing process dumps all night long.

So my bet for a short slogan for Linq would be on:

```
Code Less, Spend More (on cpu and ram of course)
```

This is more a Linq issue then an issue with extension methods, but anyways, if the IEnumerable had been meant to have a Count() method, or string an IsValidEMail method, the architects would put them there in the first place wouldn't they?

Another thing with the extension methods.

Assume you have a code block which the compiler gives an error for a missing method, which is actually an extension method, and which is in what assembly and in which class who knows. Visual Studio itself can't tell you so far either.

Anyways.

I would suggest 4. Actually, this is called the [Mediator Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern)

I would even suggest using a re-usable mapper for that purpose who will not even know any of your classes and will still be able to map one to another.

One of them: http://automapper.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks for the input :) I have the same concerns regarding solutions 1) and 2), but I just couldn't name them properly and started to wonder if it's just me being paranoid.
Regarding solution 3 this wouldn't be my first choice either, but I'm writing new functionality to existing system and all conversions were already implemented with extension methods so it got me wondering. I know actually like automapper, but unfortunately it is not used in this project. Thanks again :)

Comment: One has to be a little paranoid to write good code I guess :)